# Why does Angular binding not work for me when using ng-include as such

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, meanjs

$scope.$apply.() also does not help and just produces an error that digest() is already running. I am changing the header of the page depending on the state name. It works and the header controller does its job, but when a different HtmlTemplate is loaded its controller scope variables aren't binding to it. I have a feeling it's because I am replacing the contents of the `<header>` element that has the 'ng-controller = HeaderController' attribute and this causes some kind of conflict.

Index.html

```
<body>
    <header data-ng-controller="HeaderController" data-ng-include="headerUrl"></header>
</body>
```

header.controller.client.js

```
angular.module('core').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope','$state',
    function($scope) {
        function setHeader(stateName) {
            var headerUrl = '';

            switch(stateName) {
                case '': 
                    headerUrl = 'PrimaryHeader.client.view.html';
                    break;
                case 'viewtemplate': 
                    headerUrl = 'HeaderForProductDetails.view.html';
                    break;
                default: 
                    headerUrl = 'PrimaryHeader.client.view.html';
            }

            return headerUrl;
        }

        $scope.headerUrl = setHeader($state.current.name);
    }
]);
```

PrimaryHeader.view.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="PrimaryHeader.view.html">
    <h2>
        Hello I am the primary header template and I bind to the HeaderController scope.
    </h2>
    </div>
</script>
```

HeaderForProductDetails.view.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="HeaderForPrductDetails.view.html">
    <div data-ng-controller="HeaderForPrductDetailsController">
        <h2>
            Hello I am the header for product details and I should be able to bind to my own controller scope and that of my parent. But I don't.
        </h2>


        <div>{{somevalue}}</div> //this scope variable does not bind 
    </div>   
</script>
```

headerforproductdetails.controller.client.js

```
angular.module('core').controller('HeaderForProductDetailsController', ['$scope'
    function($scope) {
        $scope.somevalue = 'Some test string'; //this does not bind to template, yet console.log() will output it just fine.
    }
]);
```